# How to autostart nitrogen on boot

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-background, startup-applications

I am using nitrogen to span my wallpaper over dual monitors. When I boot, however, I have to manually open nitrogen to change my wallpaper again.

How can I add this as a startup application and automatically set my wallpaper?

Comment: @JacobVlijm sorry for the late reply. I don't see any answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Press ALT+F2
2. Write: `gnome-session-properties` and press ENTER
3. In the *Startup applications* window add a startup program
4. In the *Edit startup program* window fill the fields:

   - Name: `Nitrogen`
   - Command: `nitrogen --restore`
   - Comment: `Set the wallpaper using Nitrogen`
5. Save the startup program and restart your session.